# Inheritance in entity

Tags: java, hibernate

how inherience works in entity? I mean for example

```
public class Animal {
    private String name;

    //Getters and setters
}


@Entity
public class Dog extends Animal {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
}
```

But hibernate create table only with id in database, why?

Comment: Check this: http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-inheritance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mark your super class with `@MappedSuperClass`:

```
@MappedSuperClass
public class Animal {
    private String name;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your base classe is not annotated with `@Entity` so hibernate doesn't know of its existance. Inheritance in ORM is not implemented as inheritance in Java. You have specific constructs/annotations to define for table inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

From `Java Platform, Enterprise Edition: The Java EE Tutorial`:

> **37.2.3 Non-Entity Superclasses**
>
> Entities may have non-entity superclasses, and these superclasses can
>   be either abstract or concrete. The state of non-entity superclasses
>   is nonpersistent, ***and any state inherited from the non-entity
>   superclass by an entity class is nonpersistent***. Non-entity
>   superclasses may not be used in `EntityManager` or `Query` operations. ***Any
>   mapping or relationship annotations in non-entity superclasses are
>   ignored.***

So you will need something like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Animal {

    @Column
    private String name;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

Also from the abve mentioned source:

> **37.2.2 Mapped Superclasses**
>
> ***Entities may inherit from superclasses that contain persistent state and mapping information but are not entities.*** That is, the
>   superclass is not decorated with the `@Entity` annotation and is not
>   mapped as an entity by the Java Persistence provider. These
>   superclasses are most often used when you have state and mapping
>   information common to multiple entity classes.
>
> Mapped superclasses are specified by decorating the class with the
>   annotation `javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass`